# Hide section if no Playa parent

Tags: playa

I have a Playa relationship between my "News" and "Projects" channels. In a News entry, you can select a related Project, so "News" is the parent and "Projects" is the child.

I have the following code on my Project template, and it works correctly to show related News items. However, I would like to hide the entire section when there are no related News items. I thought perhaps wrapping the section with `{if no_parents}{if:else}...{/if}` would work, but I believe this type of statement must reside within the `{exp:playa:parents ... }` tag pair.

```
{!-- TO DO: put in logic to hide block if no related news --}
<!-- Sidebar Related News -->
<h4>Related News</h4>
<ul>
    {exp:playa:parents channel="News"}
    <li><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></li>
    {/exp:playa:parents}
</ul>
<!-- Sidebar Related News::END -->
```

Is there something simple here I'm overlooking?

I am using ExpressionEngine version 2.5.3 and Playa version 4.4.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="News"}

  {if count == 1}
    <h4>Related News</h4>
    <ul>
  {/if}

      <li><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></li>

  {if count == total_results}
    </ul>
  {/if}

{/exp:playa:parents}
```